# Which wireless configuration is more efficient for a high density network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I recently asked about the difference between a MIMO-capable access point and a multi-band one, and I am clear on that, now the question is:

Which configuration would be more efficient on a wireless environment with many devices (~40)…

1. Two single-band APs under the same essid?
2. A single dual-band AP?

Extra question: Is n-number of APs under the same essid the same as a single AP of n-bands? which would (theoretically) be more efficient?

Assuming every device (APs and hosts) are n/ac compliant and the network traffic would never be above the APs bandwith (~300 Mbps). And I won't need internet connection.

**TL;DR**

Should I set up a single dual-band AP or two separate single-band APs (under the same essid) for a network with ~40 devices?

Comment: Can you expand upon your definition of **efficient**? Also, you've not mentioned the physical coverage area you need to serve. Since that has a *lot* to do with reasons for using multiple APs, please indicate what role coverage area plays in your question.

Comment: Well, for efficient I mean a steady connection of good quality (no lag, downtime, and steady bandwidth speeds) and the coverage is around two floors of ~50m2 and the regular amount of obstacles of an average two story house (we rent a house for this office).

Answer (score 2):

> Which configuration would be more efficient on a wireless environment with many devices (~40)...

**In your environment I'd deploy two single-band APs** for the following reasons:

1. **Coverage would be superior.**  First, two APs enable placement options for better coverage than one can.  Second, a dual-band AP will offer 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz radios, but the 5 GHz radio will have a smaller coverage area, potentially creating an imbalance of clients on the 2.4 GHz radio.
2. **Maximum supported client count would be higher.**  Every AP has a finite limit to the number of clients it can support. A second AP increases the wireless network's device count capacity.
3. **Available bandwidth to clients would be greater.**  Same as above. More APs mean more bandwidth potential to the backbone network.

> Is n-number of APs under the same essid the same as a single AP of n-bands? which would (theoretically) be more efficient?

**No.** A single AP can only support so many clients.  Once that number (which varies depending on a variety of factors) is reached, no further clients can connect.  Adding additional APs increases the count of devices that can connect.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 differenc concepts here -

1. Dual vs Single band - Dual Bands work in different frequencies.
2. Channels.  Each channel has an amount of bandwidth, bonding channels will give you 
   more throughput in the same band.

There are problems with dual band systems - the second band is almost certainly in the 5 gig frequency and not all stuff supports it.   It also does not go as far and does not penetrate walls as well.   It can, however, go much faster because its higher frequency.

For overall general coverage you are better off putting 2 single band devices on differing channels (more then 3 channels apart) and in different parts of the building.  This will provide more reliable coverage then a single unit on both bands - UNLESS YOU ARE COMPETING WITH LOTS OF OTHER EQUIPMENT IN THE 2.4 GIG BAND.

Another consideration is the "type" of equipment.  802.11N gives 2-3 times the range and speed of 802.11G equipment.  802.11AC equipment is, apparently even better again - but most equipment will only support 802.11g or 802.11n

Comment: *5 gig frequency...can, however, go much faster.* I'm not sure I follow you here. All things being equal what about the 5 GHz frequency is "faster" than 2.4 GHz?

Comment: @twisty It can go faster for a number of reasons including - more WiFi spectrum then 2.4 gig, less competition for frequency - because of fewer devices , shorter range and reduced ability to travel through walls etc (and more transitions for signal to ride on - but that's really just restating more spectrum in a different way)

Comment: I'm not sure we're making an "all things equal" comparison when referring to things like device count or less competition on the frequency. Suppose one found an area where every 5 GHz channel was congested but no one was broadcasting on 2.4 GHz? That doesn't make 2.4 GHz inherently faster even though in *that* environment it certainly would be the "faster" choice. Make sense?